# How can I have a Windows VM running in a Windows remote server?

Tags: virtual-machine, vpn, remote-desktop, hyper-v, windows-server

For academic purpose I would like to have some virtual machines of windows server.

In my local machine I already have VirtualBox so I thought buying a Windows remote server to then install Hyper-v and create the VMs that I need. My goal is also to access the remote server by a VPN. But the Windows VPS that I found don´t support Hyper-v.
This is a short-term academic work with a low buget. Can you give me a hint about which tecnhologies are the best for this purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a VM running on a VPS if it's already running Windows?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm a beginner. By what you wrote I can undertant that a VPS is already a VM. My plan is to have more than one VM in the same remote server. Thanks.

Comment: If you need multiple Windows Server VMs you would have to license each of those VMs, which is the reason, your VPS provider prevents you from doing that yourself.  Your VPS would also have to be powerful enough to run multiple VMs, and when you break down the cost, you would be paying around the same costs (you would barely break even on that).

Comment: **There is no solution to your problem, that doesn't involve the improper licensing of Windows Server, that meets the requirements you describe.**  Here is the real problem, multiple VPS accounts will be sharing resources on the same server, so allowing those accounts to run their own hypervisor would prevent that.  However, there are VPS providers that offer VPS for the purpose you describe.  You would need to find a provider that offers a VPS that allows you to run ESXi.  By running ESXi you will be able to run any (ESXi) VM you want

Comment: @Ramhound: Wrong. One can **rent a Windows server** for free. See my answer below.

Comment: @harrymc - “Hopefully, this includes Windows Server.” - You don’t actually seem sure about that.

Comment: @Ramhound: No documentation, but there isn't much point otherwise for having a cloud server, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a low-budget low-running academical project you may use Microsoft's
[Azure free account](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/windows-server-on-azure/).

This trial account will give you 12 months of free services, up to $200 credit,
which include Windows Virtual Machines. Hopefully, this includes Windows Server.

Comment: I chose your answer because gives a solution even though it's yet to be check . You simple don't say that it's imposible. Even with the constrains that I put, can be many solutions each one not filling one of the constrains. I could then chose the best solution.

Comment: It works! I already deployed a Windows Server 2019 VM in Azure. I even can have multiple VM's and connected them by a virtual network. Azure is a good choice to learn managing Windows OS and also learn Azure. There are plenty of documentation in the net about Azure. Thanks.